Strapi v4.25 api/auth/password-change not allowed
I have been scouring the net and the Strapi doc, that is not super clear, on how to get this method to work. The route is opened in my Strapi settings, but to no avale. I am unable to get this to work. Could someone please help me.
The user has been created through the Strapi admin interface. In the doc, it talks about resetting the password only working with the users registered with the email registration procedure. Does this apply to the password-change route also?
Here is my queryMutation :
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from "axios";

// Define the payload and response types
interface PasswordChangeVariables {
    currentPassword: string | number;
    password: string | number;
    passwordConfirmation: string | number;
    token: string;
}

interface FavoritesMetierResponse {
    data: any;
}

// Custom hook to add favorite question
export const usePasswordChange = (
    onSuccess: (data: FavoritesMetierResponse) => void
) => {
    return useMutation<
        FavoritesMetierResponse,
        AxiosError,
        PasswordChangeVariables
    >({
        mutationFn: async ({
            currentPassword,
            password,
            passwordConfirmation,
            token,
        }: PasswordChangeVariables) => {
            let url: string;
            url = `${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/password-change`;

            try {
                const response: AxiosResponse<FavoritesMetierResponse> = await axios({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: {
                        currentPassword,
                        password,
                        passwordConfirmation,
                    },
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                    },
                });
                return response.data;
            } catch (error) {
                if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
                    throw error;
                } else {
                    throw new Error("An unexpected error occurred");
                }
            }
        },
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            onSuccess(data); // Call the original onSuccess callback
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            if (error.response) {
                console.error("Error code:", error.response.status);
            }
        },
    });
};

I hope someone will be able to guide me in the correct direction, because this is driving me nuts!!
I've read the Strapi v4 and just in case the v5 docs also.
I have looked at older posts on this site that were not the solution.
